# Replace Environment with @Value in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can i replace `Environment` with `@Value`?

I have a config and want to replace `Environment` and `getProperty`:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean("googleRabbitService")
    public RabbitService getGoogleRabbitService(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return new RabbitService(
                environment.getProperty("rabbit-service.google.request-exchange-name"),
                environment.getProperty("rabbit-service.google.request-queue-name"),
                environment.getProperty("rabbit-service.google.response-exchange-name"),
                environment.getProperty("rabbit-service.google.dead-exchange-name"),
                rabbitTemplate
        );
    }

    @Bean("amazonRabbitService")
    public RabbitService getAmazonRabbitService(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return new RabbitService(
                environment.getProperty("rabbit-service.amazon.request-exchange-name"),
                environment.getProperty("rabbit-service.amazon.request-queue-name"),
                environment.getProperty("rabbit-service.amazon.response-exchange-name"),
                environment.getProperty("rabbit-service.amazon.dead-exchange-name"),
                rabbitTemplate
        );
    }
```

With `@Value("${rabbit-service.google.request-exchange-name}")` straight in the constructor I get the error: `Annotations are not allowed here`.

I could use fields:

```
@Value("${rabbit-service.gogle.request-exchange-name}")
private String googleRequestExchange;
@Value("${rabbit-service.gogle.request-exchange-name}")
private String googleResponseExchange;
...
```

And then:

```
public RabbitService getGoogleRabbitService(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return new RabbitService(
                googleRequestExchange,
                googleResponseExchange,
                ...
                rabbitTemplate
        );
```

But I will have to create a bunch of fields. Is there any way to use `@Value`?

Comment: try using `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: Then you also need to define the fields representing the properties  what the user would not like.

Comment: e.g. `public RabbitService getAmazonRabbitService(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate, @Value("${rabbit-service.gogle.request-exchange-name}") ) {//...}` does not work for you? Just tried something similar locally without any problems

Comment: Since you're using Spring Boot, go ahead and use `@ConfigurationProperties` as suggested. You'll probably want to define a POJO `RabbitTemplateProperties` and have a `Map<String,RabbitTemplateProperties>` on your base class to hold the multiple parallel configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

    @Bean("googleRabbitService")
    public RabbitService getGoogleRabbitService(
                    @Value("rabbit-service.google.request-exchange-name") String requestExchangeName,
                    @Value("rabbit-service.google.request-queue-name") String requestQueueName,
                    @Value("rabbit-service.google.response-exchange-name") String responseExchangeName,
                    @Value("rabbit-service.google.dead-exchange-name") String deadExchangeName,
                    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return new RabbitService(
                requestExchangeName,
                requestQueueName,
                responseExchangeName,
                deadExchangeName,
                rabbitTemplate
        );
    }
```